# Does Compiz support Multipointer X?

Tags: input-devices, multipointerx

I know it supports touch, I'm referring specifically to the ability to have more than one pointer (cursor) as an input. This was supposed to be complete by 0.9.4 but I've not been able to find out if it is actually so.

I'm well aware that you can already have more than one pointer. I just want to know if Compiz has fully formed support.

Comment: I am curious, how do you think compiz should support MPX? Can you explain a bit more about the task that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Aras: MPX support would basically mean that I could use two mice with separate cursors without issue, and if the toolkit supports it (GTK+, Qt, etc), then I could use those mice separately in different applications.

Comment: Have you looked at [userful](http://userful.com/)? They are one of the most established platforms as far a support for multiple mouse and keyboard goes, so if there is any support for compiz and multiple mouse, I would expect to see it there.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg: yep :). Still need an answer as well.

Comment: @RolandTaylor I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=921240
i did some research, and it looks like this forum link had a possible solution, but it involved compiling code.

it confused me, but someone here might be able to make sense of it.

http://who-t.blogspot.com/2012/01/multitouch-in-x-touch-grab-handling.html

this is the blog of the guy whos been handling it with some more recent information.

EDIT: to answer your question, compiz does not support it as of now, at least by default.